# How do I update the reference to an HTML element after I used appendChild with native javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm using native javascript to append an element to my DOM, which disappears after X seconds.

To append the element I create a document fragment with a function `createHTML` I then append this element to my container element.

```
var elementHTML = '<div>Test element appended</div>';
    elementHTML = createHTML(elementHTML);      
document.getElementById('append-container').appendChild(elementHTML);
```

I then set a timeout that removes the element from the DOM after x seconds

```
setTimeout(function() {
    elementHTML.parentNode.removeChild(elementHTML);
}, 2000, elementHTML);
```

Now this won't work because when you use appendChild, the elements get moved and the reference to the element is lost. I'm looking for a way to update the reference for `elementHTML` to the element I just appended to the DOM.

Basically I'm looking for the jQuery reference funcionality without using jQuery.

I could use a randomly generated ID to target the element or add a class and loop trough all the elements with that class and target the last one, but  these methods feel ugly.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of callback when you append something to the DOM to target what you just appended or if my logic in going about this is just plain wrong.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/pafke/39oprywx/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that a `DocumentFragment` will move the *contents* of the fragment into the new place in the DOM, but the fragment itself will remain a fragment, not directly attached to anything:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

> If the given child is a DocumentFragment, the entire contents of the DocumentFragment are moved into the child list of the specified parent node.

After all, otherwise, if the HTML string is

```
<div>Test element appended</div><div>Test element 2 appended</div>
```

what could the appended `documentFragment` refer to? It's couldn't be just one or the other `<div>`, nor could it be the parent element (which was already in the DOM, and was not created with the fragment).

So, once a `documentFragment` is appended, it cannot be removed all in one go.

If the fragment is guaranteed to contain only one element, like in your example, then select that one element and append *it* instead (and then you can properly reference its `parentNode`).

```js
// though using a documentFragment in the first place is a bit odd
// if you're not going to append it

var createHTML = function(htmlStr) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
  while (temp.firstChild) {
    frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
  }
  return frag;
}

var appendItems = function() {
  const elementHTML = '<div>Test element appended</div>';
  const fragment = createHTML(elementHTML);
  const fragmentElm = fragment.children[0];
  document.getElementById('append-container').appendChild(fragmentElm);
  setTimeout(function() {
    fragmentElm.parentNode.removeChild(fragmentElm);
  }, 2000, elementHTML);
}

document.getElementById('test-append').addEventListener('click', appendItems);
```

```html
<div id="append-container">

</div>

<button id="test-append">
  Test
</button>
```

Another option is to iterate through all appended nodes and `.remove()` them:

```js
var createHTML = function(htmlStr) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
  while (temp.firstChild) {
    frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
  }
  return frag;
}

var appendItems = function() {
  const elementHTML = '<div>Test element appended</div><div>Test element 2 appended</div>';
  const fragment = createHTML(elementHTML);
  const fragmentElms = [...fragment.children];
  const container = document.getElementById('append-container');
  fragmentElms.forEach((elm) => {
    container.appendChild(elm);
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    fragmentElms.forEach((elm) => {
      elm.remove();
    });
  }, 2000, elementHTML);
}

document.getElementById('test-append').addEventListener('click', appendItems);
```

```html
<div id="append-container">

</div>

<button id="test-append">
  Test
</button>
```

Comment: I wasn't even aware I could add multiple siblings via this method. In my usecase, there will always be a single parent element, so I'm going with your first option.

Comment: If there's guaranteed to be a single parent, then you can ditch the fragment entirely and simply return `temp`'s `firstChild`

Comment: I was using the fragment because I want to add an eventlistener to part of the added element. I thought this was not possible without fragment. I now found the issue lay in the fact that I was targeting a part of the dynamic element with document.getElementById while it was not yet added to the DOM. This was why is WAS working with fragment. This is a different issue which I need to inspect further before asking follow up questions. Your provided sollution is still valid for the question as is, hence I will keep it accepted.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to replace getElementById  with querySelector

Answer (score 1):

Appending the nodes in the `while` loop is unnecessary: [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Replacing_the_contents_of_an_element) already does that for you.

```
var createHTML = function(htmlStr) {
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    return temp;
}
```

In this way – without the DOM fragment – removing the element after the timeout works as expected.